Self-Defined Problem - Verification of Work Calculation for Moving Test Charge Along Curves in the Field of a Source Point Charge
Given:
Consider a source charge \$Q\$ located at the origin \$P_Q=(0\text{m};0\text{m})\$
of a Cartesian coordinate system. A test charge \$q\$ starts at \$P_q=(4\text{m};4\text{m})\$. The charge \$q\$ can move along one of three possible curves:

\$C_1\$: along a straight line from \$P_q\$ to \$P_1=(2\text{m};2\text{m})\$
\$C_2\$: along a straight line from \$P_q\$ to \$P_2=(6\text{m};6\text{m})\$
\$C_3\$: along an arc from \$P_q\$ to \$P_3=(0\text{m};\sqrt{8}\text{m})\$

See the Figure(1) below:
Figure(1):

Problem:
The task is to determine the minimum work \$W\$ you must exert to move \$q\$ along each of these curves using the definition from https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/826893/344165:
$$ W_{\text{you}} = -\int\limits_{u=a}^{u=b} \textbf{F}_{\text{el}}(\textbf{r}) \cdot \text{d}\textbf{r}$$
where the position vector is parametrized and denoted as the shorthand  \$ \textbf{r} \equiv \textbf{r}(u) \$.
Here you can find my complete problem description:

Question:
I would like to know if my solutions for the work \$W_{\text{you}}\$ for curves \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ are correct (see the red highlighted terms on the following pages). I have written my solutions in a LaTeX document. Would it be acceptable if I post a screenshot of the pages? I hope this is the right forum for this type of question.
Please note, you do not need to solve this using vector line integrals — I’m only interested in whether my solution is equal to your solution.
My Solution for \$W_{\text{you}}\$ for \$C_1\$:

My Solution for \$W_{\text{you}}\$ for \$C_2\$:


Why don't you just change the basis vectors, make it simple, and check your own results? The work is just $U_1-U_q=\frac{k}{r_1}-\frac{k}{r_q}$ and $U_2-U_q=\frac{k}{r_2}-\frac{k}{r_q}$. Or am I missing something? I am just taking this off the top of my head, I admit. I may be forgetting something. But if not, this is an easy check to make without all the trouble maintaining both basis vectors shown in your work.
